# How to convert a XML with multiple inner loops using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML with multiple inner loops, I need to loop through 1 node after another and to display it in HTML view. The XML is given below

```
 <?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8" ?>
    <TestUser>
      <Users>
        <UserData name="test123" address="USA"/>
        <UserCommunication>
          <Communication mode="Te" value="123456879"/>
          <Qualification>
            <PG value="No"></PG>
          </Qualification>
            <Qualification>
            <UG value="YES"></UG>
          </Qualification>
        </UserCommunication>
      </Users>
      <Users>
        <UserData name="test124" address="UK"/>
        <UserCommunication>
          <Communication mode="Te" value="1567894525"/>
          <Qualification>
            <PG value="No"></PG>
          </Qualification>
           <Qualification>
            <UG value="YES"></UG>
          </Qualification>
        </UserCommunication>
      </Users>
      <Users>
        <UserData name="test125" address="INDIA"/>
        <UserCommunication>
          <Communication mode="Te" value="5465897845"/>
          <Qualification>
            <PG value="YES"></PG>
          </Qualification>
           <Qualification>
            <UG value="YES"></UG>
          </Qualification>
        </UserCommunication>
      </Users>
    </TestUser>
```

I need to display the Users details one by one in an HTML view using XSLT as in the image below.
[image]
Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: Any idea what output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Check following Code:-
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="TestUser">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border="5" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<thead>
<th bgcolor="greeen">User Name</th>
<th bgcolor="greeen">User_Addrss</th>
<th bgcolor="greeen">User_Telephone</th>
<th bgcolor="greeen">PG</th>
<th bgcolor="greeen">UG</th>
</thead>
<xsl:for-each select="//Users/UserData">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@address"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="../UserCommunication/Communication/@value"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="../UserCommunication/Qualification/PG/@value"/> </td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="../UserCommunication/Qualification/UG/@value"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```